# Why is node script failing a localhost connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I can't figure out why a script to is failing to connect to the MySQL instance.

**I can connect to the database from the mysql client on the command line, with the exact same credentials.
I can connect to the database from a remote client, using the same credentials.**

The database connect script works fine if I set the parameters to a remote database.

Neither host or socket parameters works through the script.
I make dumb mistakes at times but if this is another one, I can't see it.

An outside observer would help me here.

==================== DB Connect code

```
var db = require('./config');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: db.db_parms.host,
    port: db.db_parms.port,
    user: db.db_parms.user,
    password: db.db_parms.password,
    database: db.db_parms.context,
    debug:true
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log("SQL CONNECT ERROR: " + err);
    } else {
        console.log("SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.");
    }
});

connection.query("SELECT now()", function(error,results,fields) {
    console.log("Results:" + results);
    console.log("Fields:" + fields);
});


exports.connection = connection;
```

=== Error Stack returned:

```
SQL CONNECT ERROR: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/db/db_connect.js:19:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
```

========= config.js with host = 'localhost':

```
var db_parms = {
host: 'localhost',
port: 3307,
user:'foo',
password:'bar',
database:'thisone'
}

exports.db_parms = db_parms;
```

========= config.js with host = socket:

```
host: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
```

=== Error Stack returned:

```
SQL CONNECT ERROR: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:3307
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kingram/node/apps/fss_register/db/db_connect.js:19:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
```

I'm not sure if the error from the socket is a permissions issue or not and if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, a check of the my.conf shows that the bind-addresss was set to the IP of the server and not to localhost.

Setting `host: '<ip-address>'` fixed the issue.